# Laravel 4 index.php not loading bootstrap/autoloader.php

Tags: laravel

I've seen a few other topics like this, but none of the solutions have helped. Basically it seems like my index.php isn't loading anything that's outside of the web root. The file paths are correct, as artisan commands work as expected and if I move the bootstrap folder it breaks. I have tried composer updating, installing, changing permissions, putting in the absolute paths - but no joy. This is working perfectly on my localhost, but the exact copy transferred to a VPS isn't. Is there a PHP setting I am missing that denies includes from outside the web root? Please help!

Comment: Is your VPS using apache2.4? There has been some default changes with permissions when accessing files outside web root compared to apache2.2.

Comment: It might be the PHP version on VPS. Is it showing a blank page? Is the PHP version on VPS greater or equal than 5.4?

Comment: Make sure you're mapping the host to the public folder and not the root directory.